# finding numbers that end in 5

Tags: python

I am trying to print out all the numbers from 1 to 100 that end in 5. This is what I have:

```
 for i in range (1, 100):
      if (i/10) == 5:
           print(i)
```

Why does this print out 50?

Comment: It prints 50 because 50 divided by 10 is indeed 5.

Comment: While the answer you accepted is perfectly fine, the shortcut way to do this is: `for i in range(5, 100, 10): print i`.

Comment: Better still is to use itertools to reason about infinite lists (like all multiples of 5). This is what partially inspires the creation of list comprehensions in Haskell, which is what inspired them in Python too.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You want to use modulo `%` as oppose to division. Modulo gets the remainder.

```
for i in range (1, 100):
    if (i % 10) == 5:
        print(i)
```

Comment: @kachilous vote my answer as being right, please. Whole reason why I use this site is for the points. :-D

Comment: @FinalForm: yeah, and when your answer isn't appreciated and downvoted, you delete it... ;)

Comment: @phant0m dude are you following me?! :-D No, that's somewhat of a jaded view on why I do that. I actually delete it when I realize someone else gave a better answer, and I don't want future visitors to be confused by my "wrong" answer.

Comment: I just happened to comment on a few of your answers recently and noticed them to be deleted soon after ;) - "wrong" answers are usually found out given by their ratings

Comment: @phant0m I don't agree. I have some answers that have some down votes, but I work with the questioner to get the right answer. And in the end, it's what he wanted and his "green check" more than makes up for the down votes.

Comment: @phant0m Additionally, you can say.. I'm a phantom following you in terms of points. :-D :-p :-)

Comment: ;) You were just asking for this because of the reoccuring comment about "vote my answer as being right, please"

Comment: @phant0m You could almost say... stackoverflow would be "point"less if people didn't give points. :-) :-D

Answer (score 6):

Because 50 / 10 is 5. What you really want is probably this:

```
for i in range(100):
    if i % 10 == 5:
        print i
```

% is the modulo operation and gives you the remainder of the integer division of two numbers.

Comment: Note that the OP is (most likely) using py3k --> `print(i)`

Comment: Probably true, blame the habit. ;)

Answer (score 5):

Why test the values at all? Just generate the ones you want in the first place.

```
for i in range(5, 101, 10):
    print (i)
```

Comment: This code actually does something different from that of the accepted answer. :)

Comment: @jena: You just need to replace the second `5` with `10`

Comment: @kindall: i'm not sure i understand how this code works. Could you explain?

Comment: @kachilous: the third parameter is the "step" parameter. The first value to be yielded by range will be 5, then, range() will increment this value by `10` instead of `1` for each succeeding value.

Comment: @phant0m: is that the general way to increment for loops in python?

Comment: In Python, `for` loops don't increment. Instead, they get one item after another from some iterable object (such as a list). It just so happens that `range()` makes a list (in Python 2.x; in Python 3 its behavior is slightly different), and you can set the starting number, ending number, and step for the numbers in the list. So the answer to your question is yes, that (or `xrange()`) is how you do it in Python, but it's important to understand that there are two parts: `range()` which produces a list, and `for` which gets one item after another from the list produced by `range()`.

Comment: While this answer solves the OPs immediate problem, it's not a good way of handling this general kind of problem. For example, how would this generalize if you want all numbers that end with '5' and also serve as the hypotenuse of some right triangle triplet? Or what if you want all numbers from the Fibonacci sequence that end with 5 in a particular range? The general paradigm for this is to create a generator that enumerates the difficult-to-compute portion, and then use something like `takewhile` to limit it inside a certain range. Then you have the flexibility to return it as a `list` later

Comment: Agreed. Different problems usually require different approaches.

Answer (score 0):

This is a great way to become familiar with [itertools](http://docs.python.org/library/itertools.html)

From IPython shell:

```
In [5]: import itertools

In [6]: fives = itertools.count(start=5, step=10)

In [7]: fives.next()
Out[7]: 5

In [8]: fives.next()
Out[8]: 15

In [9]: fives.next()
Out[9]: 25

In [10]: fives.next()
Out[10]: 35

In [11]: fives = itertools.count(start=5, step=10)

In [12]: tmp = itertools.takewhile(lambda x: x <= 100, fives)

In [13]: tmp
Out[13]: <itertools.takewhile at 0x171f65f0>

In [14]: list(tmp)
Out[14]: [5, 15, 25, 35, 45, 55, 65, 75, 85, 95]
```

It's also a fun history lesson, because list comprehensions and generators in Python have a lot in common with their motivating ancestors from Haskell. Search this page for infinite lists to see what I mean: [(link)](http://learnyouahaskell.com/starting-out).